# How can I use SMOP (Matlab to Python Converter)/

Tags: python

I have a Matlab code by .txt format file. I want to use this code in python, but matlab code is so long. So, I'll use SMOP, but there is no manual, as I found.

Where can I found SMOP example or manual this case (for .txt file)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run `smop` on a .txt file you will get the following error:

`Ignored: 'file.txt' (unexpected file type)`

The simple solution here is to rename `file.txt` to `file.m` then invoke smop like so:

`smop file.m`

Assuming you don't get errors this will output `file.py` into the same directory as `file.m`.

smop doesn't support all MATLAB syntax and, sadly, appears to no longer get updates so you may find quite a few issues converting. The Github repo is here: https://github.com/victorlei/smop/ if you need to get the scripts and modify them for your use case.